# What is the sequence of functions in the Laravel Auth Contracts?

Tags: php, laravel

I am [adding a Custom User Provider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers) in Laravel 5.7.

I understand that my Custom User Provider implements the User Provider contract, which consists of 5 functions, and that my Custom User Model implements the Authenticable contract, which contains another 6 functions.

I want to understand the sequence of the functions when a user logs in to the Laravel application. I am trying to use the [Laravel logging feature](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/logging) to document the sequence, but since I am struggling to construct this, I can only get so far. Here's what I have:

**1. retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)**
Receives credentials from login form.
Query user from storage.
Return "implementation of Authenticable."

**2. validateCredentials(Authenticatable $user, array $credentials)**
Receives $user from retrieveByCredentials.
Compare the user password to provided password.
Return true if they match.

**3. getAuthIdentifier()**
Return the primary key of the user.

And now I'm stuck. I've done research and found in the documentation (and lots of other places) where the functions are described, but cannot find where the login sequence is described.

Can someone complete this list? And for that matter, is my list so far accurate?

Thank you!